# Diferença entre AnsiString,WideString, UnicodeString, ShortString e String e como converter

Tags: delphi, string, conversão-de-tipo

Durante meu aprendizado de Delphi eu vejo implementações que usam `AnsiString`,`WideString`, `UnicodeString`,`ShortString` e `String` porém não sei a diferença entre eles.

Outra coisa que sempre me ocorre é que tento salvar algum tipo em outro e ele me retorna o erro que deve ser convertido, entretanto sempre tenho dificuldade para fazer isso da maneira correta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `AnsiString`: string composta por caracteres ASCII. Cada `Char` possui exatamente 1 bytes. Um ponteiro para uma `AnsiString` (`^AnsiString`) equivale a `char*` em C;
- `WideString`: existe apenas por compatibilidade com o Windows. Cada `Char` possui 2 bytes, e deve ser utilizada em funções da Win32 com parâmetros `LPWSTR`, realizando um cast para `PWChar`;
- `UnicodeString`: string unicode. Por padrão UTF-16 (ou pelo menos era quando pesquisei pela última vez), mas pode assumir outras codificações, como UTF-8.
- `ShortString`: equivale a string antiga do Pascal, com sua limitação de de 255 caracteres.
- `String`: nas versões mais novas do Delphi (2007 em diante), equivale a `UnicodeString`. Antigamente equivalia a `AnsiString`.

Tanto `AnsiString` quanto `UnicodeString` são mais do que um simples `array of Char`, sendo que elas possuem informações de página de código e tamanho. Porém, para facilitar o cast destes tipos para `PChar` e suas variações, estas informações ficam nos endereços anteriores ao retornado pelo operador `@`.

**Conversão**

A conversão entre elas é feita automaticamente. Único cuidado que deve ser tomado, é que dados podem ser perdidos durante a conversão devido ao tipo não suportar alguma característica da string de origem.

Por exemplo, converter `UnicodeString` para `AnsiString`, pode haver perda devido aos caracteres Unicode poderem ocupar mais que 1 byte.

Conversão de `AnsiString` (ou `UnicodeString`) para `ShortString`, haverá perda de dados se a string de origem for maior que 255 (`Length(origem) > 255`).

Comment: A respeito das conversões entre eles você sabe me dizer como funcionam?

Comment: Me esqueci! Editei a resposta.

Comment: Agradecido amigo :D

Comment: Por favor, a `ShortString` que você disse corresponder a `string` antiga do **Pascal** mas com 255 caracteres apenas, ela é então do tipo `AnsiString` (com 255 caracteres apenas)?

Comment: @JamesTK Sim: a `string` antiga é igual a `ShortString`, e a `AnsiString` é igual a `ShortString` mas sem a limitação dos 255 caracteres. Portanto, uma `AnsiString` pode conter uma `ShortString`, mas uma `ShortString` não necessariamente poderá conter uma `AnsiString`.