# Como passar uma string como parâmetro para uma dll C#

Tags: delphi, dll

Tenho uma dll feita em C# com um método que recebe um parâmetro do tipo string, criei uma função no Delphi que chama esse método e passa a seguinte string no parâmetro: 'D:\Bancos\Teste.fdb', coloquei um messagebox na dll apenas para conferir como o parâmetro estava chegando e o unico valor que chega é o caractere 'D' o restante da string não vem. Tem alguma forma de resolver? Segue abaixo trecho do código:

dll em C#:

```
[Guid("36CEE06F-247C-48B4-A8BB-0E591CEF58BE")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class ReportService
{
    [DllExport]
    public static bool ListaComprasResumida(string pathBanco, string codEmpresa)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(pathBanco);

        Thread.CurrentThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

        var frm = new FrmListaComprasResumido(pathBanco, codEmpresa);
        frm.ShowDialog();

        return true;
    }
}
```

Chamada da função no Delphi:

```
uses    
function ListaComprasResumida(pathBanco: string; codEmpresa: string): Boolean; stdcall; external 'Modules.dll';

procedure TRelatorio.btnComprasResumidoClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  caminho : string;
  codigo : string;
begin  
  caminho := txtBanco.Text;
  codigo := txtCodEmpresa.Text;
  ListaComprasResumida(caminho, codigo);
end;
```

Comment: Tente enviar como WideString ou AnsiString...

Comment: Obrigado, AnsiString resolveu meu problema. Muito obrigado mesmo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passar por parâmetro do Delphi para a DLL(qualquer linguagem, principalmente VB) utilizar `WideString` ou `AnsiString`.

`AnsiString`: string composta por caracteres ASCII.

`String`: nas versões mais novas do Delphi (2007 em diante), equivale a UnicodeString. Antigamente equivalia a AnsiString.

[Fonte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51308/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-ansistring-widestring-unicodestring-shortstring-e-string-e-com)